# Is there a way to undo a migration on Django and uncheck it from the list of showmigrations?

Tags: python, django, migration

Actually, what I do is:

- Delete the migration file.
- Delete the row from the table of django_migrations on the database.
- Delete the changes applied by the migration that I want to delete or unapplied.

I want to know if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can revert back by migrating to the previous migration. See the migrations folder of your app and then see all the migrations

Say for an example, if your migrations are something like below ordered number wise and latest migration 0012_latest_migration is applied currently.

```
0010_previous_migration
0011_next_migration
0012_latest_migration
```

And You want to go back to  0010_previous_migration

```
./manage.py migrate my_app 0010_previous_migration
```

and then you can delete all migrations after that like here delete both 0011_next_migration and 0012_latest_migration as you already applied   0010_previous_migration.

If you're using Django 1.8+, you can show the names of all the migrations with

```
./manage.py showmigrations my_app
```

To reverse all migrations for an app to initial or start, you can run:

```
./manage.py migrate my_app zero
```

Comment: Unfortunately I ran into inconsistent migrations.  Is there a way to force `./manage.py migrate my_app zero`?

Comment: Same here, inconsistent migrations

Comment: Just delete all migrations except initial__***** and then try running  migrate.

Comment: doing so gave me `ORA-02299: cannot validate (C##DB.APP_C_TABLE_I_733ACFD3_U) - duplicate keys found`  database is oracle